# Guidance with DDS Setup

Tags: ros2, network, rmw

I recently stumbles upon [this discussion](https://discourse.ros.org/t/ros-2-alternative-middleware-report/33771) on ROS Discourse. From my understanding of the discussion and of the report, setting up the DDS protocol to work over wi-fi networks requires a bit of expertise.

My question is: how to build up this expertise? Can you point me to some resources that can help me understand the middleware and what are the problems that arises over wi-fi connections?

I think that such a list of reference could help anybody that, like me, is working on multi-robots applications but have no experience with networking or the DDS protocol.

Thank you in advance!